# My encoder program does not print the translated message, in C

Tags: c, string, encoding, decoding

```
printf("Enter a string: ");
            fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
            printf("\n\nYour original string: ");
            puts(input);
            printf("\n\nYour coded string: ");
            for (y = 0; input[y]; y++) {
                for (z = 0; encoder[z, 0]; z++) {
                    if (toupper(input[y]) == encoder[z, 0]) {
                        input[y] = encoder[z, 1];
                    }
                }
            }
            puts(input);
```

And here is the output:

[image: Output]

If not visible:
                 Decoder

1. Encode/Decode
2. Quit
   1

Enter a string: The dog sings

Your original string: The dog sings

Your coded string:

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This would be in C, my bad for not including

Comment: What is `encoder[z, 0]`? It is either a horrible use of the *comma operator* where `encoder[0]` is the result of every call -- or it doesn't do what you think it does...

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of troubleshooting(I was at this all day before posting) I found the solution as such:

```
printf("Enter a string: ");
            fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
            printf("\n\nYour original string: ");
            puts(input);
            while (input[i]) {
                (toupper(input[i]));
                input[i] = toupper(input[i]);
                i++;
            }
            printf("\n\nYour coded string: ");
            for (y = 0; input[y]; y++) {
                for (z = 0; encoder[z][0]; z++) {
                    if (input[y] == encoder[z][0]) {
                        input[y] = encoder[z][1];
                    }
                }
            }
            puts(input);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the issue was and how this code solves it?  Code only answer tend to be considered low quality.